# Can't get data to display dynamically with JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

A bit of an overview of my project. I am trying to make a database for movies. I have a JSON file with an array of objects and I am trying to display the content in a table using JavaScript.

I have been able to display the data using a section and paragraph tag, but really would rather have it in a table. But I can't figure out why my data won't display on my page. So if I am doing something wrong in my JavaScript or somewhere else any help would be appreciated.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = function() {                       // When readystate changes
    // The following conditional check will not work locally - only on a server
    if(xhr.status === 200) {                      // If server status was ok
      responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

      var index = responseObject.movies.length;
      var condition = responseObject.movies.length - 10;
      
      // BUILD UP STRING WITH NEW CONTENT (could also use DOM manipulation)
      var newContent = '';
      var table = document.getElementById('content');
      for (var i = index - 1; i >= condition; i--) { // Loop through object

        newContent += '<tr class="event">';
        newContent += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
        newContent += '<td>' + responseObject.movies[i].title + '</td>';
        newContent += '<td>' + responseObject.movies[i].year + '</td>';
        newContent += '</tr>';
       
    }
  table.innerHTML = newContent;   
      
    }
  };


  xhr.open('GET', 'static/data/movies.json', true);        // Prepare the request
  xhr.send(null);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #FDFDFD;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#left {
    background-color: #161616;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #DB7360;
}

img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

h1 {
    color: #DB7360;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

p {
    color: #FDFDFD;
    text-align: center;
}

#right {
    background-color: #161616;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #DB7360;
}

.buttons {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}

tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}"
</head>
<body>

<div class = "container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4" id = "left">
            <img src = "/static/images/movie-thumbnail.png">
            <h1><b>Movies Database</b></h1>
            <p>This is a database for movies from 1900-2018. You can see the title of the movie and the              year it was made.</p>           
        </div>
        <div class="col" id = "right">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class = "tableHeader">Number</th>
                        <th class = "tableHeader">Movie Title</th>
                        <th class = "tableHeader">Year Made</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody id = "content">
                    
                </tbody>

            </table>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='movies-json.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JSON file is organized as:

```
{
"movies": [
  {
    "title": "After Dark in Central Park",
    "year": 1900,
    "cast": [],
    "genres": []
  },
  {
    "title": "Boarding School Girls' Pajama Parade",
    "year": 1900,
    "cast": [],
    "genres": []
  }.............]}
```

Comment: Why have you written your loop like that: `for (var i = index - 1; i >= condition; i--)`? Normally it goes `for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`. And maybe disguise the fact you're watching porn a little.

Comment: @Andy To display the movies backwards and only 10. So instead of it displaying all movies starting at 1900 it starts displaying from the most recent.

Comment: @Andy I got the json file from a python resource. That is pretty funny because the first one does seem to be porn. https://books.google.com/books?id=un1gEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA417&lpg=PA417&dq=Boarding+School+Girls%27+Pajama+Parade+movie&source=bl&ots=hwLDEM8rRE&sig=ACfU3U2sFDoThS5WSXkgto-gerev3fsbxA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGivSwqrL2AhWKkmoFHTCuDNEQ6AF6BAglEAM#v=onepage&q=Boarding%20School%20Girls'%20Pajama%20Parade%20movie&f=false